# How to specify cuda compute architecture in vim's syntastic plugin?

Tags: vim, cuda, syntastic

I use the syntastic plugin for syntax checking. Is there a way I can customize the syntax checking to work for a different cuda compute architecture than the default?

Currently is throws me an error when I use AtomicAdd function because it is not supported in the older compute architecture, but I am using a newer one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the relevant [wiki page](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/CUDA%3A---nvcc):

> By default, **nvcc** and thus syntastic, defaults to the most basic architecture. This can produce false errors if the developer intends to compile for newer hardware and use newer features, e.g. double precision numbers. To pass a specific target arch to **nvcc**, e.g. add the following to your .vimrc:
>
> `let g:syntastic_cuda_arch = "sm_20"`